# KeyError when receiving JSON in python to send JSON value to a class variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter

Looking for a bit of help please, on understand why I am getting a keyerror in my JSON loading.

Error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...\test22.py", line 108, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestClass.saved_frame))
  File "...\test22.py", line 77, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[cont]
KeyError: "<class '__main__.PageTwo'>"
```

**Goal and steps:** To have file menu (save) preserve class variables, which can then be loaded if program is exited and the relaunched, to resume the program where the save was initiated.

This will be done by class PageOne taking TestClass.saved_frame, which is stored/loaded in JSON, and open specified frame alongside relevant stored variables using the "load save" button.

I have the class variables working to properly save and load (can be done with file menu save + the "load save" main menu button in GUI in a single instance). The problem is retrieving the class variables for loading in a new instance of the program.

I am not dead set on implementing the save/load in this fashion if there is a better available. I do plan on scaling this method with more class variables if I can get it working with these two class variables (num and frame).

**Relevant code** causing issue is in the function **def load_game()**inside of  **class TestClass** and possibly JSON interaction with **def show_frame()**

**I have tried** variations of stripping quotes, iterating key/value in the JSON and selecting the relevant values, literal_eval, but each time I get KeyError.

To replicate issue, open the GUI > select num > next page > file menu and save > exit program
then open GUI again > file menu load > load save button

```
import tkinter as tk
import json
from pathlib import Path


def generated_savegame_folder():
    path = Path.cwd() / 'Save Games'
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


generated_savegame_folder()


class TestClass(tk.Tk):
    num = None
    active_frame = None
    saved_frame = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Game")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo, LoadPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

        def save_game():                                                    # JSON METHOD
            TestClass.saved_frame = TestClass.active_frame
            print("Saved as", TestClass.saved_frame)
            data = {
                "Saved Frame": str(TestClass.saved_frame),
                "Num": TestClass.num.get()
            }
            save_folder = Path.cwd() / 'Save Games'
            save_file = "saveJSON.txt"
            file_path = save_folder / save_file
            with file_path.open("w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)

        def load_game():                                            # JSON METHOD
            path = Path.cwd() / 'Save Games' / 'saveJSON.txt'
            with path.open('r') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                print("loading", data)
                for k, v in data.items():
                    print(k, v)
            TestClass.saved_frame = data["Saved Frame"]


        def menu():
            menu_bar = tk.Menu(container)
            file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
            file_menu.add_command(label="Save Game", command=save_game)
            file_menu.add_command(label="Load Game", command=load_game)
            file_menu.add_separator()
            file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
            menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
            tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menu_bar)

        menu()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        TestClass.active_frame = cont
        print("prints container(active_frame) on page change:", TestClass.active_frame)  # testing
        print("prints frame(frame.tkraise) on page change", frame)  # testing


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self,
                              text="Make a selection",
                              wraplength=450, justify='center')
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        TestClass.num = tk.StringVar(value=' ')
        command = lambda *args: PageTwo.label.config(text=PageTwo.text.format(TestClass.num.get()))
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="1", variable=TestClass.num, command=command, value="1", ).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="2", variable=TestClass.num, command=command, value="2", ).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="3", variable=TestClass.num, command=command, value="3", ).pack()

        view_selection = tk.Button(self, text="test selection", command=lambda: print(TestClass.num.get()))
        view_selection.pack()

        next_page = tk.Button(self, text="Next Page",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        next_page.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # meant to load the last open page. PageTwo, PageThree... PageTwenty, etc. Whichever was last open before (save)
        # while also loading any saved variables
        load_last = tk.Button(self, text="Load Instance Save",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestClass.saved_frame))
        load_last.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # load_last2 = tk.Button(self, text="Load JSON Save",
        #                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(restore_game))
        # load_last2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    label = ''
    text = ''

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        PageTwo.text = "The number should show up here -> {}  <- "
        PageTwo.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.text.format(''))
        PageTwo.label.pack()

        text1 = tk.Text(self)
        text1.pack()

        see_num = tk.Button(self, text="View Number",
                            command=lambda: text1.insert('1.0', TestClass.num.get()))
        see_num.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        home_button = tk.Button(self, text="Go Home",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        home_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


class LoadPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestClass()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include  the actual error in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley alright, thanks. Done

Comment: Consider this little example:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data loaded from the JSON file is string and the key `cont` in `self.frames[cont]` is expected a reference to class.

You need to save the class name, for example `"PageTwo"` instead of `"<class '__main__.PageTwo'>"` into the JSON file.  Then you need to convert the string `"PageTwo"` to reference of class after loading it from the JSON file:

```py
        def save_game():                                                    # JSON METHOD
            TestClass.saved_frame = TestClass.active_frame
            # use .__name__ to get the class name and save it to JSON file
            print("Saved as", TestClass.saved_frame.__name__)
            data = {
                "Saved Frame": TestClass.saved_frame.__name__,
                "Num": TestClass.num.get()
            }
            save_folder = Path.cwd() / 'Save Games'
            save_file = "saveJSON.txt"
            file_path = save_folder / save_file
            with file_path.open("w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)

        def load_game():                                            # JSON METHOD
            path = Path.cwd() / 'Save Games' / 'saveJSON.txt'
            with path.open('r') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                print("loading", data)
                for k, v in data.items():
                    print(k, v)
            # convert the class name to reference of class
            TestClass.saved_frame = globals()[data["Saved Frame"]] # or eval(data["Saved Frame"])
            print('loaded', TestClass.saved_frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this little example:

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(myList [10]) # This will cause a KeyError as there isn't a 10th index in the list
```

Try printing the value of `cont` and the number of entries in `frames` - I think you'll find that you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist. Printing something like this / using a Debugger to view the values

````py
Consider this little example:
```python
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(myList [10]) # This will cause a KeyError as there isn't a 10th index in the list
````

print(f"Number of Frames: {self.frames.len}, Cont: {cont}")
frame = self.frames[cont]

```
**I'm not sure what method / variabe / member variable is used to get the length, so I've just used {obj}.len here as a placeholder.**
```

Comment: Im only about a month in with programming and python, so I might not fully understand. its {(len(self.frames)} to check len, in this case im getting 3. 


That said, if you test the local save (menubar>save>main menu>load) vs the non local save (menubar>save, exit, re-open, menubar>load, Load Save Button) the print of the saved_frame value is the exact same, but the KeyError only happens in the second case.  


The local version does not save any extra variables compared to the externally saved version, so it should be getting the same outcome with regards to the length of the frame no?

Comment: The code `frame = self.frames[cont]` assigns the variable `frame` the value of the `cont`'th index of `self.frames` so you are **accessing** a value within the variable `frames`

Comment: @choy I do understand your example where the 10th index will not exist. In this case I am not interacting with the frame index as far as I am aware, but simply inserting a value into cont. Please let me know if I am wrong and what I am missing